# Changing python3 path back to default on macOS

Tags: python, bash, macos

I must have misconfigured my python3 path to point to a library.

Not quite sure how it happened but I need to change it back and having some issues

bash cmd `python3` outputs `python3:93: command not found: lxml`

I checked the bash cmd: `which python3` that outputs:

```
  python3 () {
      lxml
   }
```

This is clearly wrong, I would expect it to be:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/`

I've tried this with no luck:
`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3`

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Check `.bashrc`, etc.

Comment: What's the path of the file that `which python3` points to?  The question is: did you overwrite the binary of your python3 with that funny bash script?  Or do you just need to update a symlink?  On my system, /usr/bin/python3 is a symlink to /usr/bin/python3.5, and /usr/bin/python3.5 is the actual executable.  What OS are you on?

Comment: @JawguyChooser Yes, I accidentally overwrote the binary and I'm on osx

Comment: If you actually overwrote the binary then you need to reinstall.  As a linux user, I'm not sure how you install software on OSX.

Comment: This is not a programming question at all

Answer (score 1):

This could be as simple as undoing changes you've made to the path; you could just locate your backup bash_profile file. Assuming it wasn't deleted, there should be a backup location in your bash_profile/bashrc file. It would like something like this:

*Your previous /Users/YourUsername/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/YourUsername/....*

I'm on OSX as well, and this saved me once. Just go to the location and copy/paste the backup into your profile. Restart the terminal and hopefully, you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

If you have overwritten the binary then I would suggest simply deleting and installing Python again.

Answer (score 0):

`which python3` should return a filesystem path, but you appear to get back a shell function, which is like a fancy version of an alias in this case. What you have is a function named `python3` which, when run, tries to run a program named `lxml` (which does not exist).

How you got here is an interesting question. Presumably you wanted to run python3 and load the lxml module. In any case, you will likely find something in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files that looks like this:

```
python3() { lxml }
```

or

```
function python3() { lxml }
```

You probably need to comment that out and try again.